# Can I block Android Camera rotation?

Tags: android, rotation, actionbarsherlock

I'm using SherlockActionBar menu in my app. Now, my whole app is set to work only in Portrait mode using on all activities:

```
"android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Now, what happens is, I open camera from my app, I take pictures and on return I do some edit, and that works more or less fine.

In case that I turn the camera while taking pictures on Android 2.2., during "on resume" I can see my app in Landscape mode for a tiny second, then it figures out that it should not be in Landscape it rotates back to portrait mode but doubles my action bar, I get two Icons, two menus, and then if I continue to use my app it crashes.

Here is the log:

```
10-04 08:34:24.602: E/AndroidRuntime(8954): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-04 08:34:24.602: E/AndroidRuntime(8954): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-04 08:34:24.602: E/AndroidRuntime(8954):     at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1115)
10-04 08:34:24.602: E/AndroidRuntime(8954):     at my.specapp.apps.BitmapRender.onDraw(BitmapRender.java:58)
10-04 08:34:24.602: E/AndroidRuntime(8954):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6739)
10-04 08:34:24.602: E/AndroidRuntime(8954):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1648)
10-04 08:34:24.602: E/AndroidRuntime(8954):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1375)
10-04 08:34:24.602: E/AndroidRuntime(8954):     at android.view.View.buildDrawingCache(View.java:6499)
```

This is most likely where second menu is drawn, and then if I continue it crashes with:

```
10-04 08:35:05.242: E/AndroidRuntime(8966): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-04 08:35:05.242: E/AndroidRuntime(8966): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{bla bla/bla bla.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-04 08:35:05.242: E/AndroidRuntime(8966):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2787)
10-04 08:35:05.242: E/AndroidRuntime(8966):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2803)
10-04 08:35:05.242: E/AndroidRuntime(8966):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:135)
```

If I do not turn the device I do not get this kind of issue, so I guess I could somehow ask device not to allow camera to turn to landscape, or I have to block that my app goes to landscape mode, and that is done through manifest, so I do not understand how to fix it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: i think u didnt initialise the Paint in ur program

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding next line to your camera class:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

or to android manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".activityname" android:orientation="portrait"/>
```

Comment: My all activities do have orientation="portrait" ... I will try to add programmatically setReQuestedOrientation, but I'm not sure if that is the way to send it to Camera and tell the camera not to rotate.